# How to pass by reference in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to modify an `Object` in another class. So I have something like this:

*MainClass.as*:

```
..
var myObject:Object = new Object();
Class2_Instance.get_JSON(myObject);
trace(myObject.id); // output: undefined. whereas it should be 42. see below.
..
```

*Class2.as*

```
public function get_JSON(url:String , the_object:Object) 
{ 
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url); 
    var variables:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
    variables.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT; 
    variables.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Complete_Handler_JSON(the_object)); 
    try 
    { 
        variables.load(request); 
    }  
    catch (error:Error) 
    { 
        trace("Unable to load URL: " + error); 
    } 
} 

function Complete_Handler_JSON(the_object:Object):Function 
{
  return function(event:Event):void 
  {  
  var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);   
  the_object = JSON.parse(loader.data);     
  trace(the_object.id); //returns 42.
  };
}
```

So the JSON operation performs correctly within Class2, and it assigns the `.parse()` value to `the_object`, but I think there is something I don't understand with AS's pass-by-reference logic. Since I was expecting `myObject` in MainClass.as would change, too.

What should I do to modify the value of the function argument (myObject) directly ?

Thanks !

Comment: Objects are passed by reference by default. the_object is not myObject. Try returning the_object after you create it in Class2_Method. You may find that over the longer term, you're better off going with another design than static methods.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Thanks, today I had some difficulties in returning from a CompleteHandler (since they wait for a URLRequest to complete, "asynchronous" is the term I guess), so I was trying to find a way without return's. And what do you mean by not-static methods ? And I think I should edit my question to add the actual code.

Comment: I'm really confused here. if the_object is not myObject, then how is it "pass-by-reference" ? And in the Adobe.com manual, it says the value of myObject WILL change, but it doesn't :/ And I cannot return from CompleteHandler. So how will I save the JSON array ?

Comment: Because you create a new object when you call JSON.parse. So you passed in the_oobject, then overwrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Objects` are passed by reference.

But as i see in your code you are overwriting `the_object` by another one on the line : `the_object=JSON.parse(loader.data)`.

You can create a new variable and then copy the values in the_object:

```
var json:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
for (var k:String in json) {
 the_object[k]=json[k];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, I found a solution very similar to this now. But I'm used to do it like in the question, in C#, which is also pass-by-reference. Shouldn't it remain the way I overwrite it ? I mean, apparently properties of objects are passed by reference, but not the objects themselves. Why ?

Comment: Because now it's a totally different object. The old object is still referenced in the calling code. Note how the code above copies all the proerties from the *new* object created by JSON.parse onto your existing object.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is in this line in your event handler:

```
the_object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
```

The minute you do this, you're no longer dealing with the object which you passed in to the method. You're assigning a new value to the local variable named `the_object`. It's important to understand that objects are not passed by reference - **object references are passed by value**. So `the_object` in your method is **a copy of the reference**. When you assign a new value, that copy is overwritten with a different reference.

The solution is to pass the reference by reference - this is related to the concept of double pointers in languages such as C++, also known as double indirection. I'm not certain that this is even possible in ActionScript.

A better solution, just return the deserialized object as a return value.

Comment: Wow. this explains my question. Thank you very much Matt! Unfortunately I cannot return from this function since it runs asynchronously, but i will keep that "double reference" thing in mind. Thanks !

Comment: Ah, in an asynchronous scenario you may consider instead returning a "promise" type > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises Again I'm not sure if ActionScript supports this.

Comment: It's not the value of the object that is passed but a reference to the object. What was expecting @void was a reference to the reference ;)

Comment: @MattDavey in ActionScript, you could handle this by returning a "wrapper" object that would contain nothing at first, but the real object later and would dispatch an event when it is ready. When working with a collection, you can pass back an empty collection and just populate the contents with the results when they come in. If you're not using Flex, you have to extend the collection to be able to dispatch events when you need them.